# WebGL Not working in FF4b7 (with enabled_for_all_sites=true)

Tags: html5, firefox, webgl

I was trying to load the cool [Kataspace WebGL demo](http://kataspace.sirikata.com/) ([more info](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2010/12/kataspace-browser-based-virtual-world-built-with-webgl-and-html5.ars?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=rss)) and I get the error message *"Your browser doesn't support WebGL. Currently we recommend the latest Firefox 4 Beta for all platforms."*

I checked around and every piece of advice I can find on the internet says to set `webgl.enabled_for_all_sites` to `true` in the about:config page.  Mine is set to true yet I still receive the same message.  Does anyone know of any other items that may be conflicting with WebGL running properly?

[image: my about:config]

Answer (score 0):

I too was having the same problem. All I can recommend is to make sure you are running the latest beta, and upgrade the graphics drivers. Also try clearing your cookies and your cache. Beyond that, all that can be said is that it is a beta product and not likely to work correctly.

You should, of course, send feedback using thefeedback button on the right side of the window.